# How to speed up the process of two loops

Tags: c#, excel, for-loop

I wrote an application to generate an excel report. This report has more than 120 columns and 100 rows. The only thing that I need to print is a quantity of the product against the distributor. Products are printed as columns and distributors are printed as the rows.

Following is my complete code.

CODE IN FORM

```
custoMeth cls = new custoMeth();

        //Clear
        drill.Clear();
        distTbl.Clear();
        monthList.Clear();

        //Declarations
        divCode = int.Parse(cmbDivCode.SelectedItem.ToString());
        catName = cmbCategory.SelectedItem.ToString();
        distName = cmbDistributor.SelectedItem.ToString();
        fromDT = dtFrom.Text.ToString();
        toDT = dtTo.Text.ToString();

        monthList = cls.monthsList(this.dtFrom, this.dtTo);

        string month = cls.selectedmonth(this.dtFrom);

        // load excel, and create a new workbook
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbooks.Add();

        // single worksheet
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet Worksheet = Excel.ActiveSheet;

        // Custom Header
        Worksheet.Range[Worksheet.Cells[1, 1], Worksheet.Cells[1, 8]].Merge();
        Worksheet.Range[Worksheet.Cells[1, 1], Worksheet.Cells[2, 8]].Merge();
        Worksheet.Range[Worksheet.Cells[3, 1], Worksheet.Cells[3, 3]].Merge();
        cls.excelHeader(Worksheet, 3, 1, "Generated Date : " + System.DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString() + "", true, "none", "Left", "none", 0);

        Worksheet.Range[Worksheet.Cells[4, 1], Worksheet.Cells[4, 3]].Merge();
        cls.excelHeader(Worksheet, 4, 1, "Sound And FreeIssue Report (Division Code : " + divCode + ")", true, "none", "Left", "none", 0);

        Worksheet.Range[Worksheet.Cells[5, 1], Worksheet.Cells[5, 3]].Merge();
        cls.excelHeader(Worksheet, 5, 1, ("Report Date: " + fromDT + " To " + toDT), true, "none", "Left", "none", 0);

        Worksheet.Range[Worksheet.Cells[6, 1], Worksheet.Cells[6, 3]].Merge();
        cls.excelHeader(Worksheet, 6, 1, "Category: " + catName + "", true, "none", "Left", "none", 0);

        cls.excelHeader(Worksheet, 8, 1, "Distributor", true, "none", "Left", "none", 20);

        int row = 8;
        int col = 2;

        #region Print Product Names
        if (catName == "All")
        {
            //sqlData = "SELECT DISTINCT Commission, ProductName FROM Drill INNER JOIN Product ON Drill.Commission = Product.CommissionCode AND Drill.DivCode = Product.DivCode ";
            //sqlData = sqlData + "WHERE TRMM = '" + month + "' AND Drill.DivCode = '" + divCode + "' AND Commission NOT IN ('xxx') ORDER BY Commission";

            sqlData = "SELECT DISTINCT Commission FROM Drill WHERE TRMM = '" + month + "' AND Drill.DivCode = '" + divCode + "' ORDER BY Commission";
            comTBL = cls.data(sqlData, myConnection, comTBL);
            prBar.Maximum = comTBL.Rows.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < comTBL.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string sqlPrd = "SELECT ProductName FROM Product WHERE CommissionCode = '" + comTBL.Rows[i]["Commission"].ToString() + "' AND DivCode = '" + divCode + "'";
                string productName = cls.GetValue<string>(sqlPrd, myConnection);
                cls.excelHeader(Worksheet, row, col, productName, true, "none", "none", "Bottom", 5, 90); //comTBL.Rows[i]["ProductName"].ToString()

                col = col + 1;
                prBar.Value = i;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sqlData = "SELECT DISTINCT Commission FROM Drill WHERE RCateg = '" + catName + "' AND TRMM = '" + month + "' ORDER BY Commission";
            comTBL = cls.data(sqlData, myConnection, comTBL);
            prBar.Maximum = comTBL.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < comTBL.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string sqlPrd = "SELECT ProductName FROM Product WHERE CommissionCode = '" + comTBL.Rows[i]["Commission"].ToString() + "' AND DivCode = '" + divCode + "'";
                string productName = cls.GetValue<string>(sqlPrd, myConnection);
                cls.excelHeader(Worksheet, row, col, productName, true, "none", "none", "Bottom", 5, 90);

                col = col + 1;
                prBar.Value = i;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        row = 9;
        col = 1;

        #region Distributor
        if (cmbDistributor.SelectedItem.ToString() == "All")
        {
            string sqlDist = "SELECT DISTINCT StkCd FROM Drill WHERE DivCode = '" + divCode + "' AND TRMM = '" + month + "'";
            distTbl = cls.data(sqlDist, myConnection, distTbl);
        }
        else
        {
            string sqlDistCode = "SELECT Code FROM Distributors WHERE Name = '" + distName + "' AND Active IN ('True') AND  DivCode = '" + divCode + "'";
            distCode = cls.GetValue<string>(sqlDistCode, myConnection);
            string sqlDist = "SELECT DISTINCT StkCd FROM Drill WHERE DivCode = '" + divCode + "' AND  StkCd = '" + distCode + "' AND TRMM = '" + month + "'";
            distTbl = cls.data(sqlDist, myConnection, distTbl);
        }
        #endregion

        prBar.Value = 0;
        prBar.Maximum = distTbl.Rows.Count;

        for (int j = 0; j < distTbl.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            col = 1;

            string sqlDistName = "SELECT Name FROM Distributors WHERE Active IN ('True') AND Code = '" + distTbl.Rows[j]["StkCd"].ToString() + "' AND DivCode = '" + divCode + "'";
            distName = cls.GetValue<string>(sqlDistName, myConnection);
            cls.excelHeader(Worksheet, row, col, distName, true, "none", "Left", "none", 20);

            col = 2;
            prBar1.Maximum = comTBL.Rows.Count;

            for (int p = 0; p < comTBL.Rows.Count; p++)
            {
                sqlDmg = "SELECT StkCd, SUM(Qty) AS Qty FROM Drill ";
                sqlDmg = sqlDmg + "WHERE StkCd = '" + distTbl.Rows[j]["StkCd"].ToString() + "' AND TRMM = '" + month + "' AND Commission = '" + comTBL.Rows[p]["Commission"].ToString() + "' AND PrtID IN ('D') AND DivCode = '" + divCode + "'";
                sqlDmg = sqlDmg + "GROUP BY StkCd";

                drill = cls.data(sqlDmg, myConnection, drill);
                int qty = 0;
                if (drill.Rows.Count > 0)
                { qty = int.Parse(drill.Rows[0]["Qty"].ToString()); }
                else
                { qty = 0; }
                qty = (qty * -1);
                cls.excelHeader(Worksheet, row, col, qty);
                col = col + 1;
                prBar1.Value = p;
            }

            row = row + 1;
            prBar.Value = j;
        }

        Excel.Visible = true;
```

cls file

```
public void excelHeader(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet Worksheet, int row, int column, string value, Boolean bold, string size, string hAlign, string vAlign, int colWidth, int orientation)
    {
        Worksheet.Cells[row, column].Value = value;
        Worksheet.Cells[row, column].Font.Bold = bold;

        if (size != "none")
        { Worksheet.Cells[row, column].Font.Size = size; }

        if (colWidth != 0)
        { Worksheet.Columns[column].ColumnWidth = colWidth; }

        if (hAlign == "Left")
        { Worksheet.Cells[row, column].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft; }
        else if (hAlign == "Center")
        { Worksheet.Cells[row, column].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter; }
        else if (hAlign == "Right")
        { Worksheet.Cells[row, column].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight; }
        else
        { Worksheet.Cells[row, column].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignGeneral; }

        if (vAlign == "Left")
        { Worksheet.Cells[row, column].VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft; }
        else if (vAlign == " Center")
        { Worksheet.Cells[row, column].VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter; }
        else if (vAlign == "Right")
        { Worksheet.Cells[row, column].VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight; }
        else
        { Worksheet.Cells[row, column].VerticalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignGeneral; }

        Worksheet.Cells[row, column].Orientation = orientation;

    }

public DataTable data(string sql, SqlConnection conn, DataTable dt)
    {
        dt.Clear();
        SqlCommand queryCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryCommand);
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }
```

This code is working but take too much time. Sometimes it gives me the error "timeout expired. the timeout period elapsed prior to completion or the server is not responding"
Please Help.
Thank You.

Comment: Too much of contents, please edit your post and add only necessary things

Comment: with all do respects sir I only posted my code in the form and two methods in the class file that I used in the form code. I thought those are necessary.

Comment: **Definitely** stop writing SQL as if each table needs to be accessed separately. Take your existing queries, read up on *joins* and try to re-write them so that you execute a *single* query that retrieves *all* data in one go. Not knowing your data, I'm not going to attempt that myself but that's got to be one of the worst performing parts of the code here.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I'm trying to rewrite the query but if we get all the data at once how can we create the column headings.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is 100% correct!

Comment: So the only way to speed up this process is rewriting the query. I'm trying to write the query with joining tables but I don't understand how to get the column and row headings at one go.

Comment: I think the point is to not have an SQL query running in each iteration of a for loop. Try to retrieve all of the data for that loop in one query.